# Getting INVALID_ARGUMENT error when passing zero to a view function with a parameter of type address?

Tags: solidity, addresses, payable

I recently upgraded to solidity 0.8.1 from 0.4.21.  I have a *view* function in my contract with an address parameter.  In the past I could pass 0 for this argument and that would be written to the contract.  Now, I get an INVALID_ARGUMENT error with argument="address" and value=0, with the offending address parameter's name in the second argument error field.

I use the value zero to let the contract know that the address has not been received yet (i.e. - the same idea as an uninitialized user).  Later when the address becomes available the correct value is set.

Am I right in believing the latest code does not allow zero addresses?  If so, what is the "standard" technique for passing a value to a view function with an "address" type parameter to let it know that the address isn't known yet?  In other words, that it should be treated as an "unitialized" address?

Also, can I convert a plain "address" type value passed to a (non-view) function and convert it to a "address payable" value so it *can* now be used in a value transfer (i.e. - be "paid")?  Or do/should all addresses that will at any point in time be used for value transfers be declared as "address payable", view function or not?